# FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder not showing image preview

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm creating an android camera app and I would like to connect it to Facebook.
I created a page for my app and created an Open Graph story "x took a Photo using MyApp".
I'm using a the OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder but for some reason I havnt been able to see the preview of the attached image in the OpenGraphActionDialog which is created.

here is my code:

```
    public void shareWithFacebook(File imageFile) {

    // get session
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    // make sure we have publish permissions
    boolean hasPublishPermissions = hasPublishPermission();
    if (!hasPublishPermissions) {
        if (!session.isOpened()) {
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
            openRequest.setPermissions("user_friends");
            session.openForRead(openRequest);
        }
        requestPublishPermissions(session);
    }

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files.add(imageFile);

    OpenGraphAction action = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost("mycameraapp:took");
    OpenGraphObject picture = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("mycameraapp:picture");
    picture.setProperty("title", "");

    action.setProperty("picture", picture);

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "picture" )
            .setImageAttachmentFilesForObject("picture", files, true)
            .build();
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentOpenGraphActionDialog(this))
        shareDialog.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
 action.setProperty("previewPropertyName", picture);
```